# Batch file that checks connectivity and restarts a program when not having internet connection

Tags: windows, batch-file, connectivity

I am using PrivateInternetAccess for a couple of automated tools, but upon losing the internet connection its killswitch activates, cutting off the internet connection. The internet connection will be lost until either manually reconnecting or restarting the application (which makes it auto connect at startup).

To further clarify, I need a batch file that:
 1. Checks if there is an internet connection every 15 seconds
 2. If there is no internet connection, end all tasks called pia_manager.exe. Normally there should be one, but occasions arise that there are 2.
 3. After performing step 2, wait one moment to go back to step 1.

I hope I clarified my question enough. I know multiple people who have the same issue with PrivateInternetAccess and I am surprised nobody has asked the question yet.

Please help me out. Cheers!

Comment: There is no edit box. I meant: after performing step 2, wait one **minute** to go back to step 1

Comment: just finally found a way based on some other scripts around here.

Answer (score 0):

**How to reconnect Private Internet Access after killswitch disconnect**

This script will check for its connectivity every 15 seconds and reconnect PIA. Use the bottom ping line to set the
interval in seconds. Keep the first ping line at seconds, as PIA might need up to 30 seconds to be connected.

```
@echo off&cls

:loop
Echo Testing connection...
ping www.google.com >nul || (
  Echo Restarting PIA...
  taskkill /im pia_manager.exe /f
  ping localhost -n 15 >nul
)
ping localhost -n 15 >nul
goto:loop
```